# problem with auto_route package after upgrading flutter to ^2.0.0

Tags: flutter, upgrade, router

My code was working without problem. But after the update I had problems in my "router.gr.dart" associate.

```flutter
// **************************************************************************
// AutoRouteGenerator (router.gr.dart)
// **************************************************************************

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/localisationscreen_page.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/loc-products-screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/forgot_password_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/register_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/set_location_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/root_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/routes/router.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/notification_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/trending_restaurant_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/restaurant_details_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/bookmarks_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/filter_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/search_results.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/review_rating_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/add_ratings_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/menu_photos_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/preview_menu_photos.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/categories_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/category_detail_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/find_friends_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/settings_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/change_password_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/change_language_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/edit_profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:potbelly/screens/new_review_screen.dart';

class AppRouter {
  static const loginScreen = '/';
  static const localisationScreen = '/localisationscreen_page';
  static const splashScreen = '/splash-screen';
  static const forgotPasswordScreen = '/forgot-password-screen';
  static const registerScreen = '/register-screen';
  static const setLocationScreen = '/set-location-screen';
  static const homeScreen = '/home-screen';
  static const rootScreen = '/root-screen';
  static const profileScreen = '/profile-screen';
  static const notificationsScreen = '/notifications-screen';
  static const trendingRestaurantsScreen = '/trending-restaurants-screen';
  static const restaurantDetailsScreen = '/restaurant-details-screen';
  static const bookmarksScreen = '/bookmarks-screen';
  static const filterScreen = '/filter-screen';
  static const searchResultsScreen = '/search-results-screen';
  static const reviewRatingScreen = '/review-rating-screen';
  static const addRatingsScreen = '/add-ratings-screen';
  static const menuPhotosScreen = '/menu-photos-screen';
  static const previewMenuPhotosScreen = '/preview-menu-photos-screen';
  static const categoriesScreen = '/categories-screen';
  static const locProductsScreen = '/loc-products-screen';
  static const categoryDetailScreen = '/category-detail-screen';
  static const findFriendsScreen = '/find-friends-screen';
  static const settingsScreen = '/settings-screen';
  static const changePasswordScreen = '/change-password-screen';
  static const changeLanguageScreen = '/change-language-screen';
  static const editProfileScreen = '/edit-profile-screen';
  static const newReviewScreen = '/new-review-screen';

  static final navigator = ExtendedNavigator();
  static Route<dynamic> onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    final args = settings.arguments;
    switch (settings.name) {
      case AppRouter.loginScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => LoginScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.localisationScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => Localisation(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.splashScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => SplashScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.forgotPasswordScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => ForgotPasswordScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.registerScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => RegisterScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.setLocationScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => SetLocationScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.homeScreen:
        if (hasInvalidArgs<Key>(args)) {
          return misTypedArgsRoute<Key>(args);
        }
        final typedArgs = args as Key;
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => HomeScreen(key: typedArgs),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.rootScreen:
        if (hasInvalidArgs<CurrentScreen>(args)) {
          return misTypedArgsRoute<CurrentScreen>(args);
        }
        final typedArgs = args as CurrentScreen;
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => RootScreen(currentScreen: typedArgs),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.profileScreen:
        if (hasInvalidArgs<Key>(args)) {
          return misTypedArgsRoute<Key>(args);
        }
        final typedArgs = args as Key;
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => ProfileScreen(key: typedArgs),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.notificationsScreen:
        if (hasInvalidArgs<Key>(args)) {
          return misTypedArgsRoute<Key>(args);
        }
        final typedArgs = args as Key;
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => NotificationsScreen(key: typedArgs),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.trendingRestaurantsScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => TrendingRestaurantsScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.restaurantDetailsScreen:
        if (hasInvalidArgs<RestaurantDetails>(args, isRequired: true)) {
          return misTypedArgsRoute<RestaurantDetails>(args);
        }
        final typedArgs = args as RestaurantDetails;
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => RestaurantDetailsScreen(restaurantDetails: typedArgs),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.bookmarksScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => BookmarksScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.filterScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => FilterScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.searchResultsScreen:
        if (hasInvalidArgs<SearchValue>(args)) {
          return misTypedArgsRoute<SearchValue>(args);
        }
        final typedArgs = args as SearchValue;
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => SearchResultsScreen(typedArgs),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.reviewRatingScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => ReviewRatingScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.addRatingsScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => AddRatingsScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.menuPhotosScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => MenuPhotosScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.previewMenuPhotosScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => PreviewMenuPhotosScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.categoriesScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => CategoriesScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.locProductsScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => LocProductsScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.categoryDetailScreen:
        if (hasInvalidArgs<CategoryDetailScreenArguments>(args,
            isRequired: true)) {
          return misTypedArgsRoute<CategoryDetailScreenArguments>(args);
        }
        final typedArgs = args as CategoryDetailScreenArguments;
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => CategoryDetailScreen(
              categoryName: typedArgs.categoryName,
              imagePath: typedArgs.imagePath,
              numberOfCategories: typedArgs.numberOfCategories,
              selectedCategory: typedArgs.selectedCategory,
              gradient: typedArgs.gradient),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.findFriendsScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => FindFriendsScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.settingsScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => SettingsScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.changePasswordScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => ChangePasswordScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.changeLanguageScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => ChangeLanguageScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.editProfileScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => EditProfileScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      case AppRouter.newReviewScreen:
        return CupertinoPageRoute<dynamic>(
          builder: (_) => NewReviewScreen(),
          settings: settings,
        );
      default:
        return unknownRoutePage(settings.name);
    }
  }
}

//**************************************************************************
// Arguments holder classes
//***************************************************************************

//CategoryDetailScreen arguments holder class
class CategoryDetailScreenArguments {
  final String categoryName;
  final String imagePath;
  final int numberOfCategories;
  final int selectedCategory;
  final Gradient gradient;
  CategoryDetailScreenArguments(
      {@required this.categoryName,
      @required this.imagePath,
      @required this.numberOfCategories,
      @required this.selectedCategory,
      @required this.gradient});
}
```

"ExtendedNavigator" is displayed as an error although before it was working:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gTq5.png)

Then I have "hasInvalidArgs" and "misTypedArgsRoute" which show up as errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZKgo.png)

And finally I have "unknownRoutePage" which no longer works either:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMp8P.png)

If anyone can help me that would be nice :)
I've been looking for a solution for several days now but I can't find anything :/

Comment: In my "pubspec.yaml" folder :
 ''' version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.5.2 <3.0.0'
  flutter: ^0.1.2
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  carousel_slider: ^1.4.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.22.0
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  auto_route: ^2.0.0
  animations: ^2.0.1
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.0
  flutter_feather_icons: ^2.0.0+1
  geocoding: ^2.0.0
  geolocator: ^7.4.0
  image_picker: ^0.8.3+3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  build_runner:
  auto_route_generator: ^2.0.0
 '''

Comment: Try `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`. Then run the `build_runner` command again.

Comment: yes i tried to do that but it doesn't work ...

Comment: Did you get errors while running them? or It didn't solve the issue?

Comment: I needed to upgrade "image_picker" to version "0.8.3 + 3" (because I need to use XFile. XFile is only available in higher versions). So I change the version but error with the others plugins installed. So I upgraded all my plugins. Following that my "route" no longer worked ... As I need to upgrade to do what I want to do, I have to find a solution to my update of the "route" file. I was using "auto_route: ^ 0.3.1" but I upgraded to "auto_route: ^ 2.0.0". And for "auto_route_generator: ^ 0.3.2" I switched to "auto_route_generator: ^ 2.0.0".

Comment: Everything was working before the update. So I think my code is too old for "auto_route". But I don't know how to change my code so that it works under this version.

Comment: run the `build_runner` command again. Follow the `auto_route` documentation for the changes.

Comment: yes precisely I have been doing this for several days but I do not understand what I have to modify so as not to have any more errors ...

Comment: The problem came from the updates I made to "pubspec.yaml". So I took my old "pubspec.yaml" back and work around the basic problem I had. I kept "image_picker: ^ 0.6.5 + 3".